# Read whole file using XStream

Tags: java, xml, io

I want to read the contents of a xml file using XStream. I want to read the whole file, but don't know what to put in the while condition, so that XStream doesn't throw a `java.io.EOFException` exception.Basically I want to stop the cycle when I reach the end of the file. The code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
    Reader someReader = new FileReader("filename.xml");

    ObjectInputStream in = xstream.createObjectInputStream(someReader);

    while (???) {            
        Person a = (Person)in.readObject(); // Person is just a class containing a String and an int
        a.print();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation: If they're stored as a list in the XML, try reading it in *as a list*:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people = (List<Person>) xstream.fromXML(someReader);
```

According to the [XStream API](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html), the `XStream` object can read from any number of different inputs, including directly from a `Reader`.  If you do read in directly from a list, you will need to alter your code slightly to allow for implicit collections.  A good working example of using implicit collections can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18291798/2030691).

Alternately, if you do want to use an `ObjectInputStream`, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2626163/2030691) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626193/2030691) for solutions of how to tell when you've reached the end of an `ObjectInputStream`.